# Go algorithm for looping through servers in predefined ratio

Tags: algorithm, loops, go

I am tying to make a algorithm that can loop true things, backend server in my case by a pre defined ratio.

for example I got 2 backend servers

```
type server struct {
    addr string
    ratio float64
    counter int64
}

// s2 is a beast and may handle 3 times the requests then s1 *edit
s1 := &server{":3000", 0.25}
s2 := &server{":3001", 0.75}

func nextServer() {
    server := next() // simple goroutine that provides the next server between s1 and s2
    N := server.counter / i
    if float64(N) > server.ratio {
        //repeat this function
        return nextServer()
    }

    server.counter += 1
}    

for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    nextServer()
}
```

- s1 has 250 as counter (requests handled)
- s2 is huge so he has 750 as counter (requests handled)

this is a very simple implementation of what I got but when i is like 10000, it keeps looping in
nextServer() cause N is always > server.ratio.

as long as i is around 5000 it works perfect. but I think there are better algorithms for looping in ratios.

How to make this simple and solid?

Comment: That depends on your desiderata. The value of a solution for this problem depends on how you want to balance security and simplicity.

Comment: i just want to loop true things by there ratio. i can scale it when i have a solid loop

Comment: In a simple and relatively secure solution, the servers would be in a list. Let's say `r` is the sum of their ratios. `nextServer()` would then generate a uniformly random real number from the interval `[0, r)`, and pick a server based on that. In your case, if you have the list `{s1, s2}`, `nextServer()` would pick `s1` when it rolls something between `0` (inclusive) and `0.25` (exclusive), and `s2` when it rolls between `0.25` and `1`.

Comment: seems interesting can you explain the interval more in depth?

Comment: btw the sum of there ratios is always 1.0

Comment: [Real intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29) denote the 'endpoints' of an interval and whether that endpoint is included or excluded (in other words, whether that side of the interval is closed or open). The interval `[0, r)` contains all `x` for which `0 <= x && x < r` holds.

Comment: Uhm, you are aware that you are trying to rebuild a loadbalancer?

Comment: its actualy a reverse proxy that makes me rebuild my binary without dropping the listener. But it i want to scale it more so it can act as a loadbalancer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

type server struct {
    addr  string
    ratio float64
}

var servers []server

func nextServer() *server {
    rndFloat := rand.Float64() //pick a random number between 0.0-1.0
    ratioSum := 0.0
    for _, srv := range servers {
        ratioSum += srv.ratio //sum ratios of all previous servers in list
        if ratioSum >= rndFloat { //if ratiosum rises above the random number
            return &srv //return that server
        }
    }
    return nil //should not come here
}

func main() {
    servers = []server{server{"0.25", 0.25}, server{"0.50", 0.50}, 
            server{"0.10", 0.10}, server{"0.15", 0.15}}

    counts := make(map[string]int, len(servers))
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        srv := nextServer()
        counts[srv.addr] += 1
    }
    fmt.Println(counts)
}
```

Yields for example:

```
map[0.50:56 0.15:15 0.25:24 0.10:5]
```

Comment: sometimes i kick myself in the head, and ask myself why i make simple things so hard. This is something i can work with. thx alot

Comment: All solutions are easy when you see them ;)